# How to extract the error message sent by the server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, http, redux

server:

```js
    // code
      return res.status(400).json("Email already exist");
```

client:

```js
export const register = async (credentials, dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post("/auth/register", credentials);
    dispatch(success(res.data));
    document.cookie = res.data.access_token;
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch(register_error());
  }
  dispatch(end());
};
```

When that message is sent, things move into the `catch` block and I don't know how to exact the `Email already exist` message from the `err` object.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping a console.log around the `err` parameter and see what it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's **err.response.data** in the catch block.

[Error Handling in Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors)

Answer (score 1):

According to Axios documentation, you can access errors as follows

```
axios.get('/user/12345').catch(function (error) {
if (error.response) {
  // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
  // that falls out of the range of 2xx
  console.log(error.response.data);
  console.log(error.response.status);
  console.log(error.response.headers);
} else if (error.request) {
  // The request was made but no response was received
  // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
  // http.ClientRequest in node.js
  console.log(error.request);
} else {
  // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
  console.log('Error', error.message);
}
console.log(error.config); 
});
```

Using the **validateStatus** config option, you can define HTTP code(s) that should throw an error.

```
axios.get('/user/12345', {
  validateStatus: function (status) {
  return status < 500; // Resolve only if the status code is less than 500
  }
});
```

Using **toJSON** you get an object with more information about the HTTP error.

```
axios.get('/user/12345').catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error.toJSON());
});
```